# In D3.js how can I update an existing <g> element instead of appending a new one?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I am building a Bar Chart in React with D3 using the code below. Whenever the data changes, the svg adds a new top level  tag instead of updating the existing one.

How can I modify the `const chart = svg.append("g");` line to update the top level g tag instead of adding a new one to the svg every time the chart data changes?

Thank you

```
function BarChart() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(defaultData);
  const svgRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = select(svgRef.current);

    const chart = svg.append("g");

    const xScale = scaleBand()
      .range([0, width])
      .domain(data.map((s) => s.language))
      .padding(0.4);

    const yScale = scaleLinear().range([height, 0]).domain([0, 100]);

    const makeYLines = () => axisLeft().scale(yScale);

    chart
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
      .call(axisBottom(xScale));

    chart.append("g").call(axisLeft(yScale));

    chart
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "grid")
      .call(makeYLines().tickSize(-width, 0, 0).tickFormat(""));

    const barGroups = chart.selectAll().data(data).enter().append("g");

    barGroups
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", (g) => xScale(g.language))
      .attr("y", (g) => yScale(g.value))
      .attr("height", (g) => height - yScale(g.value))
      .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth());

    barGroups
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "value")
      .attr("x", (a) => xScale(a.language) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
      .attr("y", (a) => yScale(a.value) + 30)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text((a) => `${a.value}`);
  }, [data]);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="BarChart2">
        <svg ref={svgRef} />
      </div>
      <br />
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setData((prev) => prev.map((x) => ({ ...x, value: x.value + 3 })))
        }
      >
        Update Data
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: After you declare `svg`, you can delete all it's child nodes with `svg.selectAll('*').remove()`, then append your g element.

Answer (score 0):

An idiomatic D3 uses a selection for doing what you want, e.g.:

```
let chart = svg.selectAll(".foo")
    .data([true]);

chart = chart.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "foo")
    .merge(chart);
```

The `data([true])` is just a way to show that the data doesn't matter, but we append one element to the enter selection.

With that change, the code works like this: the first time it runs the update selection is empty (there is no `.foo`), and the group is appended. On the second time onwards `chart` selects the already appended group.

Pay attention to the fact that this only deals with the parent group: depending on your enter/update/exit selections (or the lack thereof) other elements will be duplicated. Finally, do not remove elements just to create them again, that's not idiomatic D3 and adds a burden to the browser.